# Can two different programs have complete access to single INI file at the same time?

Tags: ini, lazarus, file-access, fpc

I have two different programs that need to have complete access to a single INI file to read and write into at the same time. Is this possible?

I am using fpc 2.6.2 and Lazarus 1.0.12.

Comment: In few words: no in case if you are using standard routines. At the other point of view there are several decisions about sharing of content of the files generally and text files in particular. Subversion or Git for example is doing this.